# Instant image preview not functioning

Tags: reactjs, image, state

I have an image file input and I am trying to display the image directly after the user uploads the file. I made sure everything else that I am aware of works, however, this piece of code:

```
<img src={this.state.imgSrc} />
```

Will only display a tiny image file icon instead of the image itself.

I seriously have no clue what is wrong because I cross-referenced it with multiple different tutorials and those seem to work for some reason. Help much appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to display a preview of the image immediately after the user *selects* the image **and** before the user *uploads* the image.

Here's a Sandbox using an approach that I used with react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to show an image preview.

Hope it helps!

[image: Edit silly-forest-icjqi]